# How to print a progress bar in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, progress-bar

I'm new to Fortran. I'm trying to write a subroutine in Fortran that prints a progress bar when called inside a loop. Although my code for the progress bar works fine as a standalone program, it stoped working when I moved it to a subroutine. Instead of printing a single progress bar it prints n copies of the progress bar. I'm using the gfortran compiler.

I'm trying to use this progress bar to track the progress of calculations being done in the loop.

I just don't understand why the original program which had the `write` statements inside a loop, worked flawlessly, but when I removed the loop and moved the code to the subroutine it stoped working.

The output is like this:

```
 progress:  99.9 %[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||] 

 progress:  99.9 %[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||]
```

My subroutine code is as follows

```
subroutine print_progress_bar(progress) 
implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: progress
    integer :: i
    integer :: PBWIDTH = 60
    character(len=60) :: PBSTR = "||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||"
    character(len=60) :: CTPBSTR
    integer :: val
    integer :: lpad
    integer :: rpad
    
    write(*, *)
    write(*, '(a17)', advance='no') ' Progress : 00.0%'
    
    ! Test the progress bar by incrementing progress
      
    val = int(progress * 100)
    lpad = int(progress * (PBWIDTH + 1))
    rpad = PBWIDTH - lpad
    CTPBSTR = PBSTR(1:lpad)
    CTPBSTR(lpad + 1: PBWIDTH) = ' '
    
    
    write(*,'(a, a, f5.1, a2, a1, a1)', advance="no") & 
          char(13), ' progress: ', progress*100, '%'
    write(*, "(A)", advance="no") "["
    write(*, "(A)", advance="no")  CTPBSTR
    write(*, "(A)", advance="no") "]"
    write(*, *) ""
    
    flush(6)

end subroutine print_progress_bar
```

I'm calling it from a do loop as follows

```
progress = 0.00

do i = 1, atomCount 

    call print_progress_bar(progress)

    progress = i / real(atomCount - 1)
    
end do
```

my original code was as follows:

```
program test_progress_bar 
  implicit none

    real :: progress
    integer :: i
    integer :: PBWIDTH = 60
    character(len=60) :: PBSTR = "||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||"
    character(len=60) :: CTPBSTR
    integer :: val
    integer :: lpad
    integer :: rpad
    
    progress = 0.01
  
    write(*, *)
    write(*, '(a17)', advance='no') ' Progress : 00.0%'

    ! Test the progress bar by incrementing progress
    do i = 1, 100 
      
      val = int(progress * 100)
      lpad = int(progress * (PBWIDTH + 1))
      rpad = PBWIDTH - lpad
      CTPBSTR = PBSTR(1:lpad)
      CTPBSTR(lpad + 1: PBWIDTH) = ' '
      
      
      write(*,'(a, a, f5.1, a2, a1, a1)', advance="no") &
            char(13), ' progress: ', progress*100, '%'
      write(*, "(A)", advance="no") "["
      write(*, "(A)", advance="no")  CTPBSTR
      write(*, "(A)", advance="no") "]"

      progress = progress + 0.01


      call sleep(1)
    end do
    
    write(*, *) ""

end program test_progress_bar
```

Thanks

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Thank you for your reply, I'm running this on Mac OS, with the zsh shell, but the original standalone progress bar program worked okay on Mac OS and on linux Ubuntu and mint. I don't understand what is going wrong because the original program had this code inside a loop, I just removed the loop to create the subroutine. As I'll be using the progress bar to show the progress in the loop.

Comment: You are right. You do not need to use any escape sequences. Not advancing the record and writing to the right columns should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple, the

```
write(*, *)
```

, at the start of the subroutine, and the

```
write(*, *) ""
```

, at the end of the subroutine, will both advance to a new record. Therefore, with every call to the subroutine you will write to a new line.

Just keep the exact write statements that you had in the original loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone, I managed to fix the issue by doing the following:

first I deleted the temporary variable `progress`then removed the call for the `print_progress_bar` subroutine, and then added it again as follows:

```
    do i = 1, atomCount 

        call print_progress_bar(real(i)/real(atomCount))

    end do
```

I have absolutely no clue why this fixed the issue, but it did.

Comment: From this answer I have no idea why it worked either; see Vladimir's answer for the reason you are getting new lines. I suggest rather than showing the changes you edit your answer to show the complete, working program.